# Jasmin/Karma Unit Test HTML Custom Element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, custom-element

I have created some custom elements in my project. I want to write some testings for the lifecycle event, listeners, and custom methods with `Jasmine` and `Karma`.

I know some libraries you can define the custom element in the page, render the page and test against that page. But I would prefer them just stay in Jasmine's `describe` format.

The part I found very confusing is most of the stuff(methods, observers) I want to test do not return a value but manipulating the DOM or change itself's attributes, which I am not sure if it defeats the purpose of unit tests.

Comment: Any progress with this? Looks like there isn't much help from dev community. However you can share your findings/ how did you test custom-element for others like me who're planning to do the same.

Comment: thanks for the comment @Nachiketha I think the answer I found is append the custom element into the DOM of your test and then tweak your test. It's definitely doable, but varies case by case. If you have an example, I may can help.

Comment: We wanted to analyse generic testing scenarios before using custom-elements in our project. Thats all. Thanks